# Scala PacktRat Parser Restrict Operator to Exactly One

Tags: parsing, scala

Currently I am using the Scala PackratParsers in Scala 2.9.2 
The production looks like this:

```
  lazy val andExpression: PackratParser[Expression] = equalityExpression | expression ~ "&" ~ expression ^^ {
      case x ~"&"~y => AndExpr(x,y)
    }

  lazy val orExpression: PackratParser[Expression] = andExpression | ( expression ~ "|" ~ expression ) ^^ {
      case x ~"|"~y => OrExpr(x,y)
    }
```

It works great with the following input

```
"a & b", "a | c", "(a & b) | c"
```

However, I just discovered that my parser is too greedy.

```
"a && b", "a &&& b", "a ||||| b"
```

It parses just fine. I believe I am just missing an explicit matcher count on the combinator. What is it to exactly say `e ~ "&".{1} ~ e` ? How do just match exactly one occurrence of an operator and nothing more and nothing less?

The parser that I am writing treats an Expression similarly to an XPath

```
lazy val absolutePath: PackratParser[NodePath] = "/" ~ relativePath ^^ {
    case "/" ~ rel => NodePath( rel.nodeExpr, true );

  }  

  lazy val relativePath: PackratParser[NodePath] = repsep( nodeExpression , "/" ) ^^ {
    case x => 
        if ( debug) printf("x=%s NodePath\n",x ); 
        NodePath( x , false )
```

And you are correct.

```
   lazy val nodeExpression: PackratParser[Token] = qname | variable | step 

   lazy val expression = orExpression | nodeExpression | variable | literal | function | ...
```

Since you can have empty `NodePath( List[QName]() )` then "yeah!" the Expression is empy and consequently "x &" and "& x" are parsed successfully. Hence my parser appears greedy.

Let me rephrase the question, how do I ensure `relativeExpression` contains at least one `QName`?

Essentially the set of strings `( "x" , "/x", "x/y", "/x/y", ... )` should be valid XPath like expression, but not `""`? ;-)

Comment: What is the value of `expression`?

Comment: Expression can be something like an XPath

Comment: Ok! I figured it out. lazy val relativePath: PackratParser[NodePath] = rep1sep( nodeExpression , "/" ) -- Allow one or more "nodeExpressions"

Answer (score 3):

`"&"` and `"|"` only match a single character. The only explanation I can think of is that `expression` can either be empty or be, itself `&` or `|`.